# Unable to display XML data as HTML

Tags: php, html, xml

I've load a xml file from url

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);
```

But when I echo out by php, my browser unable to read HTML tag in XML.

```
echo $child->description;
```

It display something like this.

```
<p> The secadition.</p> <p> Time isbt. <em>As offignity.</em></p>
```

Anyway to make the HTML tag readable by browser?

In XML

```
    <description>
&lt;p&gt;
 The secret of our success is very simple - we respect our clients, provide them only with the high quality commodities and work only with the best and the most reliable suppliers. What we offer is not just the reliable mechanisms, we offer stylish and desired watches that will present you as the owners of prestigious tradition.&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;
 Time is priceless, without a doubt. &lt;em&gt;As official time providers we will help you appreciate your time and with our watches you will do that with style and dignity.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
```

update

```
html_entity_decode() will solve this problem
```

Comment: are you trying to display the xml directly on the browser or are you formatting the information for a webpage?

Comment: `&lt;` is not the same as `<` even if the browser displays it like that. The source HTML is still `&lt;`.

Comment: Hi @patrickdamery, I use php to echo the data. And I wish to make the HTML tag working as well, example <h1>Title</h1> will display big title, but unfortunately those HTML tag display as a string together with content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to un-escape the html entities

Comment: if this answer helped you figure it out you should accept it or at least upvote it